# DAX function to create LY Measure without date dimension

Tags: date, dax

i´m new to DAX and want to create a measure to show LY values.There´s no date dimension. It should show Net value among HalfYear dimension e.g. 20121 (Year+HalfYear 1 or 2). How do i create such a measure? I already tried following:

```
LY = calculate(SUM([NetSales]); Table[HalfYear]-10))
```

Is there a DAX Function i can use for my issue? To get LY i have to subtract 10 from HalfYear.

please see results with FILTER function.

```
LY = calculate(SUM([NetSales]);FILTER(Table;Table[HalfYear]-10)))
```

The results for LY should appear one row over current results:

```
        LY Measure   Current Year

20141   1.328.697   1.328.697,22
20142   1.592.415   1.592.415,40
20151   1.528.698   1.528.697,85
20152   506.322.402.492 506.322.402.492,18
```

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: If you don't want to create a calendar/date dimension you can use a FILTER to SUM the NetSales values of the last year. Edit your question to include sample data and expected result.

Comment: Hi, please see edited version in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly simple (sumx of lookup to old year value). DAX-wise it goes like:

```
DEFINE MEASURE Table[LY]=SUMX(
  Table,
  LOOKUPVALUE(Table[NetSales], Table[HalfYear], Table[HalfYear] - 100)
)
EVALUATE ADDCOLUMNS(Table, "LY", Table[LY])
```